# 404 when launching Profile Manager website on Mac OS X Mountain Lion Server with Passenger loaded

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion, passenger, osx-server

I have a Mountain Lion Server installed on my Mac with Passenger installed for Apache. I also have Profile Manager enabled.

Before enabling Passenger with:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

In: /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf

i had no problems with running Profile Manager website at: http://myserver.com/profilemanager/.

Now the rails site is working fine, but I'm getting 404 from the rails app when trying to enter `/profilemanager`. To my suprise /mydevices is working fine.

This what I'm getting from the Apache log:

> example.com 10.0.1.2 - - [19/Feb/2013:13:17:54 +0100] "GET
>   /profilemanager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 431 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17" example.com 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [19/Feb/2013:13:18:01 +0100] "GET
>   /auth/verify?auth_token=D0BB6EBE-EF58-47E3-9406-A8ED97920310

What can be wrong? When I remove every file from `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites` and restart Profile Manager, the site is back. As soon as I re-enable Web server, getting 404.

Comment: Seems the rails app routes collide somehow with the /profilemanager. When I remove app folder, profile starts to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've split the hostanames, server.example.com pointing to only server specific sites. example.com pointing to folder with rails app.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same problem. I don't believe that it has anything to do with Rails. Rather it's a server configuration issue. When you add virtual hosts resolving to the same IP as your server they seem to "mask" access to the profile manager site.

I have confirmed that removing all sites from the web server section in the Server tool restores access to profilemanager.

I appears that you can either have profilemanager or server web sites from your OS X server but not both. I'm sure that's not the case so if anyone knows the correct way of setting this up please speak up.